# Accessing properties after using getdefinitionbyname

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to access properties from a class like this:

```
public class Oak extends Tree //base class for tree classes
{
    public static const CLASS_NAME:String = getQualifiedClassName(Oak);

    public var branches:Array;

    public function Oak() 
    {
        branches = 
        [
        "Leaf1",
        "Leaf2",
        ];
    }
```

The class trying to access the variable is shown here:

```
public class TreeTest extends BaseScreen //just extends Sprite, TreeTest is shown on the stage
{
    public var oak:Tree;

    private var inc:int;

    public function TreeTest(pModel:Model) 
    {
        model = pModel;

        model.createTree(Oak.CLASS_NAME);
        oak = model.getTree(Oak.CLASS_NAME);
        inc = 0;

        this.addMouseClickListener(0, treeHandler); //from BaseScreen
    }

    private function treeHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        inc++;
        this.displayText.text = oak.branches[inc];
    }
```

and the model is shown below:

```
public class Model 
{
    public var treeArray:Array;

    public function Model() 
    {
        treeArray = new Array();
    }

    public function createTree(pClassName:String):void 
    {
        var name:String = pClassName;
        var ClassReference:Class = getDefinitionByName(name) as Class;
        var classInstance:Tree = new ClassReference;
        treeArray.push([name, classInstance]);
    }

    public function getTree(pClassName:String):Tree
    {
        var treeName:String = pCharacterClassName;
        var match:Boolean = false;
        var matchArrayRef:int = 0;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < treeArray.length; i++) 
        {
            if (match == true) 
            {
                break
            }

            if (treeArray[i][0] == treeName) 
            {
                match = true;
                matchArrayRef = i;
            }
            else 
            {
                match = false;
            }
        }

        if (match == false) 
        {
            return null; 
        }
        else 
        {
            return treeArray[matchArrayRef][1];
        }
    }
```

When I ran this, I got the error "Access of possibly undefined property branches through a reference with static type Tree".

After searching for a solution, I discovered that basically means that the branches array was not in the Tree class. To confirm this, if I went and took public var branches:Array away from the Oak class and put it in the Tree class, the code worked.

Why can I not access variables defined in the Oak class, and have to put everything in the Tree base class? Even if I change var classInstance:Tree to var classInstance:Oak, or even var classInstance:Object, I still get the same error if the array is in the Oak class, not the Tree class.

Like, if I create a new class Pine which would also extend Tree, do I have to put all of Pine's variables in the Tree class too?

Comment: I'd start with Model.createTree, traced all variables and describeType(ClassReference) to understand what I get there. Then, in Model.getTree, why are you emulating the generic object basic functionality of storing key:value pairs?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, I am not very advanced in Actionscript (or OOP in general). I originally chose this method to switch between "screens", as my first method relied on a switch statement. However, I got tired of editing the switch every time I created a new screen class (since I do not know how many different screens I need). This method just allowed me write the CLASS_NAME and not have to go back into my screen manager at all, it would just work. I then tried to modify it for generating objects, as shown in the example here, but apparently it doesn't work quite like I want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing the `oak` variable as class `Tree`, so any property you reference from it should be of class `Tree`, not any subclasses, because exactly the superclass does not have them, thus compiler does not know how to address memory from `branches` property. Worse, this addressing might technically differ from subclass to subclass, an that's why directly addressing properties of a subclass via reference of type superclass is not possible.

There is a workaround. You can use `hasOwnProperty` method defined in `Object` class to check whether a certain tree has `branches`, and then address via string-based addressing like `tree["branches"]`.

```
if (tree.hasOwnProperty("branches")) {
    var br=tree["branches"];
    trace(br); //or whatever
}
```

In fact, you can even go like this:

```
if (tree is Oak) {
    var oak:Oak=tree as Oak;
    // now all oaks have branches, go get em
    trace(oak.branches);
}
```

Still, this breaks one of the object-oriented programming's core principles - you attempt to explicitly depend on subclasses having variables of certain names and are expecting them to contain values of same meaning across subclasses. Or, with the second approach, you are trying to make code know about every single subclass of `Tree` that will ever exist. Effectively you try to make subclasses behave as a superclass, without giving the superclass enough properties to provide that behavior in a common manner. This is not how OOP works. So, you should first devise a superclass by assigning it properties and methods of a **generic** `Tree`. All trees have branches, so `branches` should belong to `Tree` class. All trees can `grow()` for example, with whatever set of parameters supplied to growth, be it humidity, warmth, soil thickness, etc, but they are the same for all subclasses of `Tree`, be it oaks or sequoias, thus, `grow()` method should belong to `Tree` class as well.  They, however, grow differently, and respond to parameters differently, but this is where `override` comes to help provide different behavior in subclasses.

Comment: Hmm, well I suspected that it was probably due to my overall understanding of OOP. I've just been dabbling in Actionscript 3 (and basically OOP as a whole, as it's basically the first and only language I've been learning on and off).

Comment: Pressed enter while attempting to add space. I was trying to work with inheritance. Instead of Tree being the superclass, what if it was Plant. Then Tree extends Plant, Oak extends Tree. Plant may have grow(), therefore so do Trees and then Oaks. However, what if I also had another class Flower that extended Plant. Now, Oak may have public var bark, but Flower would not. Is there no way to specifically reference the subclasses like Oak or Flower? As you say in the first sentence, I was "referencing the Oak variable as Class Tree" but I really wanted Oak as Class Oak.

Comment: I was thinking about it some more and I guess the analogy that I'm thinking of is that something like Movieclip, which extends Sprite, still has its own properties and methods, correct? Like, Sprite does not have currentFrame or gotoAndPlay(), right? So likewise, why can't my Oak class have its own properties and methods, instead of having to define them in Tree (and then setting them in Oak or overriding)?

Comment: `Oak` can of course have it own properties and methods, it's just you should not depend in anything that accepts an instance of `Tree` to be able to use extended functionality of `Oak`. You can, however, make existing code benefit from additional code by overriding any of `Tree`'s methods on `Oak` invoking new functionality of that class.